# Could someone please explain how this while loop works?

Tags: java, while-loop

I do not understand how the while loop dissects the information. Could someone please explain how it works?

```
private static int sumDigits(int number) {
    int sum = 0;                //Initialize sum
    int rem;                    //Initialize remainder

    while (number > 0) {            //If number is greater than 0 true
        rem = number % 10;          //<-- ??
        sum += rem;                 //<-- ??
        number = number/10;         //<-- ??
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `%`, `+=` and `/` do? If you know what each operation does, you can work out an example on paper and figure this out.

Comment: "I've created a method" but you don't understand what it says. Are you *sure* that it was *you* who wrote it? Try a small program and print the results to see it in action. Learn by example.

Comment: I don't understand how you created a method but doesn't understand what it does. If this is homework and (I am not accusing) you got the code from somewhere else, note that professors check for software plagiarism, so be careful :)

Comment: Excuse me, yes I need to edit the comment. I copied the answer from a homework helping website, but I'm still unsure of how it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding this code is the use of two operators - the remainder operator `%` and the integer division operator `/`.

- The `%` operator produces the remainder from dividing by its right-hand side. In case of `% 10` this means "get the last decimal digit of the number"
- The `/` division operator discards the remainder, producing an integer result. Dividing an integer by zero discards its last digit.

For example, if you start with `n = 1234` and do

```
int d = n % 10;
int r = n / 10;
```

then `d` would be `4` and `r` would be `123`.

At this point it should be clear how the loop proceeds to termination, and how it accumulates the sum of number's digits as it goes through the iterations.

Comment: So to my understanding, if we start with n = 1234, d = 4, and r = 123. The loop would repeat, and d would = 3, and r would then = 12 and continue? If so where's the information stored and what adds them together..

Comment: @OhDavid Think of an example where `number` is `1234`. After the first iteration `number` would be `123`. After the second iteration it would be `12`. After the third iteration it would be `1`. After the forth iteration it would be zero, at which point the loop would terminate.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Could you please explain how the numbers are stored, if the variables are being replaced with new ints? and what adds the numbers?

Comment: @OhDavid I suggest you check out [this link](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/DataBasics/Mathoperators.htm) which attempts to explain integer arithmetic.

Comment: @OhDavid `number = number/10;` is an assignment. The value on the right is calculated using the old value of `number`, and then the old value is replaced with the result of calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Filled in the comments where you noted you had trouble

```
private static int sumDigits(int number) {
    int sum = 0;                //Initialize sum
    int rem;                    //Initialize remainder



 while (number > 0) {            //If number is greater than 0 true
    rem = number % 10;          //rem now contains the remainder of the number / 10
    //Keep in mind, number % 10 will give you the rightmost digit in your number
    sum += rem;                 //add the remainder to your running total
    number = number/10;         //divide your number by 10 so you can find
    //the next right most digit in your number
}
return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

This example tries to sum all the digits of a number % is used to get the last digit on each while loop and divided by 10 is done to reduce the number and sum is added for all digits see the inline comment by me

private static int sumDigits(int number) {
        int sum = 0;                //Initialize sum
        int rem;                    //Initialize remainder

```
    while (number > 0) {            //If number is greater than 0 true
        rem = number % 10; //remainder after division by 10 e.g 12%10=2
        sum += rem;  //sum=sum+rem               //<-- ??
        number = number/10;//reduce one number by dividing to 10         //<-- ??
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's step through the code with an example. Let's call `sumDigits(1234)`.

The first time through the `while` loop, `number` equals 1234. `rem = 1234 % 10`, which evaluates to `rem = 4` as the remainder from dividing 1234 by 10 is 4 (which is the rightmost digit in `number`). `sum += rem` evaluates to `sum += 4`, so the value of `sum` is 4. Since `number` is an `int`, storing the value of itself divided by 10 results in 123 being stored in  `number`.

The second time through the `while` loop, `number` equals 123. `rem = 123 % 10`, which evaluates to `rem = 3` as the remainder from dividing 123 by 10 is 3 (which is the rightmost digit in `number`). `sum += rem` evaluates to `sum += 3`, so the value of `sum` is 7, since `sum` was equal to 4 at the end of the last loop iteration. Since `number` is an `int`, storing the value of itself divided by 10 results in 12 being stored in  `number`.

Repeat this two more times, and you'll end up with `number` equalling zero (as `int(1/10)` = 0), therefore, you'll exit the loop and `sum` will contain the sum of the digits in number.

Comment: Wow perfect. Thank you very much this was the most clarifying explanation that didn't go over my head. I completely understand it now.

Comment: I've found that stepping through functions/algorithms with sample data is the best way to understand what's going on. It gets a little more complicated as you learn about more complex data types, but like they say, the best way to learn is to do - and the best way to learn what code is doing to do what the code does! Best of luck on your learning,